# Electric field and charged body

Tags: electrostatics

If an object is influenced by an electric field Then is it a charged body ? If we consider bits of paper which get influenced by electrostatic force ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definition of a charged body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288602/definition-of-a-charged-body)

Comment: I see a completely different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between insulators and conductors. In conductors, charges will move to the surface of the object, whereas charges in an insulator are not mobile. In the case of paper bits, it is the insulator case.

This post: [Excess charge on an insulator and conductor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38488/excess-charge-on-an-insulator-and-conductor) gives a detailed explanation on excess charges in insulators and conductors.

Edit: Flaudemaus provided a nice example for a conductor as a charged body: You connect capacitor plates to a voltage source and later remove the connection.

Comment: I get your thing But I thought it like this  Like if a charged body is brought closer to the bits of paper (Body charged by friction a metre scale ) Then The neutral atoms of the insulator get attracted to the charged body depending on which charged the body carries and polarisation sort of thing happens which is the reason of turbulence caused . I'm sorry If I'm too wrong for this statement but I am not that knowledgeable So please bear me

Comment: If you would not call conductors charged bodies, how would you then call the plates of a capacitor, to which a voltage is applied, with the voltage source being removed later?

Comment: Fair enough flaudemaus... I edited the answer.

Comment: Dear user227271, I am not sure whether I understand your comment correctly, but yes - The paper is polarized by the charged body. For conductors, the corresponding effect is electrostatic induction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_induction